# How do I remove the azagent the config.cmd is hanging?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

.\config.cmd remove is hanging. I am running PS latest under administrator. I run the command, log states.

```
    [2020-03-25 17:45:09Z INFO Terminal] WRITE LINE: Removing agent from the server
    [2020-03-25 17:45:09Z INFO ConfigurationStore] IsConfigured()
    [2020-03-25 17:45:09Z INFO ConfigurationStore] IsConfigured: True
    [2020-03-25 17:45:09Z INFO ConfigurationStore] HasCredentials()
    [2020-03-25 17:45:09Z INFO ConfigurationStore] stored True
    [2020-03-25 17:45:09Z INFO ConfigurationStore] Read setting file: 189 chars
    [2020-03-25 17:45:09Z INFO ConfigurationManager] GetCredentialProvider
    [2020-03-25 17:45:09Z INFO CommandSettings] Arg 'auth': ''
    [2020-03-25 17:45:09Z INFO CommandSettings] Flag 'unattended': 'False'
    [2020-03-25 17:45:09Z INFO PromptManager] ReadValue
    [2020-03-25 17:45:09Z INFO Terminal] WRITE: Enter authentication type (press enter for PAT) > 
    [2020-03-25 17:45:09Z INFO Terminal] READ LINE
```

I do not see this. Just blinking cursor. Do I need to up some rights within PowerShell? I have to close Powershell and reopen.

Answer (score 3):

This has been answered. Trying to run in the PowerShell ISE doesn't allow interactive. Run from the admin command prompt.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution here, would you please [accept your solution](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as the answer? So it would be helpful for other members who get the same issue to find the solution easily. Have a nice day:)